# Can I use my Nintendo Network ID on multiple 3DS systems?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

I have a 3DS for me, and one that the kids share. I understand that I can't use purchases from my system on the kids' one. Can I at least sign in with the same account?  I don't want to have to make a new account for the kids if I can help it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

As Nintendo's [help page](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/Nintendo-3DS/Instant-Software/Nintendo-Network-ID/Nintendo-Network-ID-826711.html) about the Nintendo Network ID states:

> You can only register a single Nintendo Network ID to each Nintendo
> 3DS system. It is not possible to register multiple Nintendo Network
> IDs on a single system.
>
> **A Nintendo Network ID registered on a Nintendo
> 3DS system cannot be registered to another Nintendo 3DS system.** If you
> wish to transfer your Nintendo Network ID and balance to another
> Nintendo 3DS system, this is only possible by performing a system
> transfer.

Comment: It sounds like this is another situation where Nintendo just won't give us another option. :(

Comment: Ashley, I dont think thats what shes asking. What shes asking is can she use the same network id on 2 different devices not if she can you 2 network id's on a single device. i think that's what james meant anyways. but i think the answer may still be no james. i just bought a second new 3ds xl today to be able to trade my pokemon between my copies of xy, and oras haha. i don't trust people for trade evolutions and moving megastones. i may get robbed smh. but ill check it out and get back to you.

Comment: @NyceHS My answer answers both. You can't use the same ID on different devices, and you can't use more than one on one system.