# Can I transfer just some game data to a new SD card?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Yesterday I bought Pokemon Yellow, and have been playing it for hours on end. Then today, I got the new Pokemon 20th Anniversary 3DS as a gift. I want to dedicate the new SD card to Pokemon, but I was wondering if I could transfer only the Pokemon Yellow and Pokemon Bank Data over, or would I have to bring all my other games with it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only copy over an entire SD card, not just certain parts of it.

Comment: You can pop the SD card into the computer and see if it looks like the data is separate.  Just don't copy/move anything for now until you're certain it is ok.

Comment: You mean that you still want to use both 3DS? Becayse you can't have your NNID on two different consoles.

Answer (score 1):

No

You must transfer all or nothing. Nintendo does this to protect it's digital content from piracy and such. You must transfer your entire account. I got the new 3ds Hyrule Edition and performed the wifi transfer from my old 3ds and it was a very strict and unforgiving process. Also only one 3ds can be attached to each account per Nintendo's [account help page](https://www.nintendo.com/3ds/nintendo-network-id/).

Also see: [Can I use my Nintendo Network ID on multiple 3DS systems?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/153222/can-i-use-my-nintendo-network-id-on-multiple-3ds-systems)

You could theoretically set up a new account on your new 3ds and use that account only for Pokemon. But you would have to buy Yellow again and start the game over.