# 3DS got stolen, can I access my Pokemon Bank from a new one?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-bank

I got my 3DS stolen 2 days ago, I rapidly changed my password so I would not risk my pokemon to be stolen from the bank. (I've been collecting them with my little brother since the first pokemon came out in 1999).

I tried to check the Pokemon Bank website and found this:

> If the Nintendo 3DS system that I downloaded and purchased Pokémon Bank for is lost, can I continue to use my previous Pokémon Bank from that lost Nintendo 3DS system on a different system in the Nintendo 3DS family?
>
> Any inquiries regarding your system in the Nintendo 3DS family are handled by Nintendo. Please contact them using the following contact information.

I tried sending a message, but got no responses since then.

Do anyone know if buying a new 3DS and using the same account will be enough to get back my pokemons or are they lost until, maybe, Nintendo answers me?

I'm really awfully pained by the idea of losing all that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your Pokebank information is tied to your Nintendo Network ID. So, yes; if you get a replacement 3DS, and login to your old NNID account on it, you will be able access and withdraw your stored Pokemon (assuming the thief did not otherwise mess with them).

**However**, the same NNID [cannot be associated with more than one 3DS at a time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/153224/30115). As a result, you will need to call Nintendo's customer service (1-800-255-3700 (6 am ~ 7 pm Pacific, everyday)) to [have them remotely unlink your NNID from your stolen system](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/261816/30115). This process can be a pain, as they will require some information from you, so be sure to have as much of it on hand as you can before calling:

> - The serial numbers of your (broken/lost/)**stolen 3DS** *and* your new **replacement 3DS**. Possible locations of the serial numbers:
>
>   - should be on a sticker on the back of the 3DS systems
>   - on the original box and user manual, if you still have them
>   - if you registered your system online with Club Nintendo, you should be able to find it online. (Not entirely sure how well this
>       works since they've re-jiggered the Club Nintendo system)
> - Your name
> - Date of birth
> - Nintendo Network ID name
> - Club Nintendo ID
> - Email address linked to either accounts
> - Downloads and purchases you’ve made with the account
> - Possibly other information to help them verify that you are the owner of the NNID.

Once you've gone through customer service (it can take up to 24 hours for the process of unlinking your NNID from your old system on Nintendo's end) you should be able to use your NNID on your replacement 3DS. I'd advise against setting up a *new* NNID while you are waiting for Customer Service to unlink your ID, as you cannot have two NNIDs on the same system.

Comment: Bought a new 3DS, everything is fine! Thanks again!